# a-entity sound component is set but not audible

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I'm very new to a-frame framework, I'm trying to build my first scene to see how things work on VR, everything is going as planned except for the sound. I've set a sound attribute  just like the one in the a-frame page,  "https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/sound.html" but the sound isn't audible. Any ideas?

```
... 
<a-scene>
      <a-assets>....<audio id="tieSound" 
                   src="tiesound.mp3"></audio>

      <a-asset-item id="TieFighter" 
                        src="tiefighter.glb"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>
...
     <a-entity 
             id="3DObject"
             gltf-model="#TieFighter" sound="src: #tieSound; volume: 2; rolloffFactor: 2; refDistance: 1; autoplay: true; distanceModel: exponential; loop: true"
             position="10 40 -900"
             scale="1.2 1.2 1.2"
             rotation="0 0 0 "
             animation="property:object3D.position.z; to: 1200;   dir: normal; dur: 15000; loop: true">
      </a-entity>
...
```

Comment: Share link to full example to reproduce so people can look at it. https://glitch.com/~aframe will do

Comment: are you sure you are close enough to hear the sound ? Its kinda pretty far away. Try placing it at '0 0 0' to verify if the component isn't working, or maybe the volume needs to be crancked up

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski tried that, no sound for some reason.

Comment: https://glitch.com/~aframe-sound-linear the yellow box has 'your' properties, and seems to be working. Did you try `0 0 0` without the animation ?

Comment: yes, I placed it on "1 1 1" still nothing is audible